Mixed mix of conditionals
In the sitcom "Married with children", two characters said the following:

Al: "If God didn't want other people to hear your voice, he wouldn't have made it so shrill".


Peggy: "If God had wanted you to have hot water, he wouldn't have given me laundry".

My questions is why, basically talking about the same situation and the same kind of hypothesis, they used different conditionals?
The next usage of a conditional in the same episode tripped me even more:

That sweet man would get me a great gift, and I'll be sitting there like a jerk with nothing for him.

Why "would" when she knows he "will" get her a present. I have never come across a mixed conditional like that, and I don't have a single idea as to how to justify its usage.
Another example: Peggy gets a bottle of champagne, but the people who gifted it to her said: we put your name on it, and Peggy responded:

To bad. It would have been a nice gift for us to give to somebody.

Why the 3rd conditonal, why about the past, doesn't she mean it's still the case? If there were no label on the champagne now, it would be a nice gift now?

You shouldn't try to learn English from a Fox sitcom. The cadence of the joke is as important as rules about types of conditionals, which aren't followed by native speakers at the best of times. And yes, the joke is that if their name wasn't on the bottle they could have given it as a gift to someone else.

Americans are not very consistent in whether we use simple or perfect tenses.

@Stuart F I wasn't asking about the joke, the joke is very simple. I just don't understand why the writer (it wasn't done of the cuff, of course) wrote it differently. Also, I wanted to hear native speakers' prospective as to how badly one of those sentences in a pair sounds to them, and if all of them make sense, if there's a difference in the way they feel.

All such questions wrongly assume that English actually has numbered conditionals. You're talking about some "toy" set of simplistic guidelines that are little more than a deceptive paedogogic model for beginning EFL student. They do not represent native speech, nor have ever done so. I'll therefore migrate this question to our site for EFL matters, where there are likely many duplicates addressing this false assumption in ways that may make better sense to you than here, like here.

@tchrist That link you give just goes to an answer to the OP's question on this site. What site is for EFL matters??

@tchrist A ' "toy" set of simplistic guidelines that are little more than a deceptive paedogogic model for beginning EFL students'.  ... The sets get more complicated as one graduates to different textbooks.

@Lambie This site, ELL, is for EFL matters. The comment was written just as the question was migrated from ELU to ELL. (Did I use too many TLAs?)

@Barmar Oh, I see. English as a foreign language. Hmm.

"[If you hadn't put my name on it] it would have been a nice gift to give to somebody [else]." Al's comment assumes that God still wants other people to hear Peggy's voice - but the tense isn't important for the meaning.

What @KateBunting: God's "timeless" anyway, so it hardly makes much sense to assign anything He does or wants to any particular time. But it it weren't for that, and the timing was important, you could in principle have If God hadn't have wanted other people to hear your voice... Or even ...wanted other people to have heard your voice... English is nothing if not flexible on such matters!

This question is similar to: Difference between "if + present, will + infinitive" and "if + present, would + infinitive". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@FumbleFingers I went over the information you provided. Yes, I know that there are many other types of conditionals, I'm just trying to undertsand the logic if there is any. Whatever the combination is, if I say, "That sweet man WOULD GET me a great gift", it's still "hypothetical", why should I use "WOULD" when I want to say "WILL" (real future), and "would" doesn't make sense as habitual here. Why "If God DIDN'T WANT other people to hear your voice" if we want to talk of something which happened in the past, we don't use "If+Past Simple" for the past. These are the moments that confuse me.

The fact that there are many combinations is fine, but the fact that change their meaning, all of a sudden, is confusing.

The issue here isn't a matter of learning the fairly pointless list of numbered conditionals (which are always "incomplete"). It's about avoiding unnecessary use of Perfect verb forms,

The 4 Conditionals
Linked in the comments: "It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.".
I think the useful bit of the 4-conditionals model is as safe, well-explored patterns that you can use to express many conditional ideas. But most native speakers don't think in those terms.
Example 1
Unfortunately, I don't think there's a good explanation beyond "it just sounds better". If we rewrite it to be exactly parallel:

AL: If God didn't want other people to hear your voice, he wouldn't have made it so shrill.
PEGGY: If God didn't want you to run out of hot water, he wouldn't have given me laundry.

Copying the structure exactly makes the retort seem a bit unnatural, like Peggy is trying too hard to come up with a good comeback. Changing the structure gives her a different character voice and makes her reply seem quicker.
Example 2

That sweet man would get me a great gift, and I'll be sitting there like a jerk with nothing for him.

I think this is a combination of a few things.
First, "he would" can be used to indicate expected/typical actions, not just theoretical actions. Example: "Kevin is banned from Disneyland because he got in a fight with a security guard." "He would do that, wouldn't he." There, "he would do that" isn't really hypothetical, since it actually happened. The speaker is just agreeing that it sounds like actions Kevin has done before.
Secondly, you can mix conditionals, so you might analyze this as the 2nd-conditional "if [past]" (an imagined future) + the 1st conditional "then [will + verb]" (the planned future response).
Thirdly, shifting to a less-hypothetical tense makes it sound more immediate, inevitable, or distressing. Here's 3 ways you might write it:

(1) He might get me a great gift, and I would be sitting there like a jerk.
(2) He might get me a great gift, and I will be sitting there like a jerk.
(3) He might get me a great gift, and then I'm sitting there like a jerk.

As we shift from 1 -> 2 -> 3, there's less "distance" from that potential (bad) future. You'd use (2) or (3) to emphasize how the conditional doesn't feel conditional.
Example 3

Too bad. It would have been a nice gift for us to give to somebody.

The 3rd conditional is generally what we use for "past possibility that is now impossible". So you might understand this as:

[If you hadn't written my name, then] it would have been a nice gift.


Not super happy with this answer, and particularly I think a bit that's missing is any explanation on what actually makes a conditional ungrammatical

Don't forget that would is also used for habitual pasts, as well as for the past of will whether meaning wanting to or going to, not merely for conditionals. He would ask and then I would leave. // Another observation worth reminding learners of is that native speakers tend to avoid complex verb constructions. One such example is how we often dispense with a perfect aspect when we can get away with it.

@tchrist but "would" is not used in habitual sense in "That sweet man would get me a great gift, and I'll be sitting there like a jerk with nothing for him."

@Kaia Thank you. I did undertsand the 3rd example this way too, just wanted to make sure. As to the 2nd example, you used "would" applying it to an action that did happen. In my example it neither happened, not was it habitual.

@Leroy To me, that one certainly looks like the past tense of will meaning is going to or perhaps is willing/wanting to, making it the same as was going to or maybe as was willing/wanting to. There seems no "conditional" protasis and apodosis pairing of clauses here. How do you see it?
